# How to create a custom 404 Error page for every language

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, templates, overrides, multilingual

I'm looking for a way to have a custom 404 error page that will appear in function of the language of the site.

So far I have created my error.php and I put it there : "templates/YourTemplate/error.php"

`<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;
if ($this->error->getCode() == '404') {
     header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
     echo file_get_contents(JURI::root().'./error-404');
 exit;
 }`

I also created my hidden menu with a blog view set to all language with the alias error-404. This menu to the articles from the "error-404" category (all language).

I can't have to alias for the same article so created the French article with error-404 and I also created the English categories with error-404-en alias. Finally, I created an association to link the two article together.

I have set every element to "no index / no follow".

I know that I could create a new template for one language and set the other one for the other language with their specific error.php, but I would like to keep the same template for both languages.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you also could use the standard 404 (or similar) php-file of your template if it already exists. The Joomla! alias standard would be /404 or /404.html according to the global configuration for the alias handling. Normally it´s no good idea to override this behaviour by hand.

I would just use

```
<?php echo JText::_('SOME_INFO_FOR_404'); ?>
```

inside the php-file. So you just need to set up the according language string overrides for title etc. and do not need separated php-files or templates.
If you do want to push special vars for the different languages, for e.g. passing different pictures, you could also use the available framework language checks.

Comment: PHP + language file is how I remember a commercial template doing it. It worked and was simple to localize. IIRC (has a BIG if)

Comment: @Ville Niemi You do not need a commercial template for that, Joomla itself replaces the JText items. Just use the override.ini for the replacements (available also at backend via Extensions -> Language -< Overrides), according to your used language(s).

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

[How to detect the current language of a Joomla! website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352241/how-to-detect-the-current-language-of-a-joomla-website)

[Creating a Custom 404 Error Page](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page)

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();

$result = $lang->getTag();

if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {

  if ($result=="en-GB") { 
      header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=31');
      exit;
  }
  if ($result=="pt-PT") {
      header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=30');
      exit;
  }

}
```

You must adapt your code, please read '[Creating a Custom 404 Error Page](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page)'